# Gerar páginas web usando Flask ou Django a partir das tabelas

Tags: java, jsf, flask, generators

Eu tenho um schema em um banco MySQL.
Eu quero gerar as páginas web a partir das tabelas deste schema.
Existe algum gerador deste em python?

Há alguns anos eu gerava um "sistema" desses usando NetBeans, nele eu criava a conexão e a partir da conexão eu gerava as classes de entidades e das entidades gerava as JPAs.
Com as JPAs gerava as interfaces JSF com primefaces.

Mas eu queria algo mais simples e direto.

Obrigado.

Comment: Ficou um pouco confusa sua pergunta... você deseja gerar as páginas a partir do schema no banco? Sem uma modelagem destas na aplicação? Aí teria que ler os metadados da base, puxar as tabelas, tipos de dados e fazer algum tratamento. Da maneira que você quer eu estou achando estranho. Talvez não esteja bem explicada a questão.

Comment: Seria isso... Ler os metadados do schema e gerar o crud.

Comment: existe o [Flask Table](https://flask-table.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)